# Unity 3, TouchScript - Detects touch position each time it changes position

Tags: unity, c#

I have a big problem here. I am making a script to detect a circular swipe, so I need to continually detect a touch position that keeps a magnitude and that the angle is relative to the former angle detected. But I cannot advance to there, because I still haven't found the proper method to detect continually (if its position changed) a touch (a same finger ID) to so proceed with that algorithm.

I'm using a library, called TouchScript, I tried with LongPressedGestures, and then with touches from the TouchManager, but they are managed by their respective handlers, and I dunno how to extract or get their data outside their handlers, so I continually check their positions (I would proceed with the TouchManager instead of the LongPressedGesture).

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using TouchScript;
using TouchScript.Gestures;
using TouchScript.Hit;
using System;
using DG.Tweening;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CircularSwipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool holded; //Flag that activates if a press is being held, and that deactivates once it is released.

    //Store the components that will form the vector of the radius of the circle with their respective components.
    public GameObject[] radiusPositions = new GameObject[2];

    float magnitude; //Stores the radius magnitude, for circle swipe on run-time calculations
    float initialAngle; //Stores the initial angle of the circle swipe request.
    float deltaX;
    float deltaY;

    void Awake()
    {
        //By no modifyng the original script, we change the time to detect longPressHandler gesture...
        GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().TimeToPress = 0.5f;

        holded = false;

        //Get both x and y components of the vector between both swipe components...
        deltaX = Mathf.Abs(radiusPositions[0].transform.position.x - radiusPositions[1].transform.position.x);
        deltaY = Mathf.Abs(radiusPositions[0].transform.position.y - radiusPositions[1].transform.position.y);

        calculateMagnitude(deltaX, deltaY);

        //The angle that will determine the range of the angle requested for the swipe.
        initialAngle = Mathf.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        Debug.Log("Delta X equals to: " + deltaX);
        Debug.Log("Delta Y equals to: " + deltaY);
        Debug.Log("Angle equals to: " + initialAngle);
        Debug.Log("Magnitude equals to: " + magnitude);
    }

    //Add both PressGesture and ReleaseGesture scripts to the object...
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        GetComponent<PressGesture>().Pressed += pressedHandler;
        //GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().LongPressed += longPressedHandler;
        GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().StateChanged += longPressedHandler;
        GetComponent<ReleaseGesture>().Released += releaseHandler;

        if (TouchManager.Instance != null)
        {
          TouchManager.Instance.TouchesBegan += touchesBeganHandler;
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        GetComponent<PressGesture>().Pressed -= pressedHandler;
        //GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().LongPressed -= longPressedHandler;

        GetComponent<ReleaseGesture>().Released -= releaseHandler;

        if (TouchManager.Instance != null)
        {
          TouchManager.Instance.TouchesBegan -= touchesBeganHandler;
        }
    }

    private void pressedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        holded = true;
        //GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().LongPressed += longPressedHandler;

        PressGesture gesture = sender as PressGesture;
        TouchHit hit;
        gesture.GetTargetHitResult(out hit);
        RaycastHit rayCast = hit.RaycastHit;

        if(rayCast.transform.gameObject == this.radiusPositions[1])
        {
            Debug.Log("Yup, started where it had to...");
            GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().StateChanged -= longPressedHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Nope, didn't start where it had to...");
        }
    }

    private void releaseHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        holded = false;
        //GetComponent<LongPressGesture>().LongPressed -= longPressedHandler;
    }

    private void longPressedHandler(object sender, GestureStateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int test = 0; 

        LongPressGesture gesture = sender as LongPressGesture;
        TouchHit hit;
        gesture.GetTargetHitResult(out hit);

        //TouchPoint point = new TouchPoint();

        Debug.Log("Test equals to: " +test);

        if(e.State == Gesture.GestureState.Recognized) //Gesture recognized, hence it is on gameObject the script is attached to...
        {
        }
    }

    private void touchesBeganHandler(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentID = 0;

        foreach(TouchPoint point in e.Touches)
        {
            currentID = point.Id;
            Debug.Log(point.Position);
            Debug.Log("Also with ID: " +point.Id);
        }

        Debug.Log("Outside the foreach: " + e.Touches[currentID]);
    }

    void calculateMagnitude(float x, float y)
    {
        magnitude = Mathf.Sqrt((Mathf.Pow(x,2)+Mathf.Pow(y,2)));
    }
}
```